# Why does BeginRouteForm write a class name to html?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm experimenting with ASP.NET MVC 2, and I have a simple form using `Html.BeginRouteForm`, which is working file, except it writes the string `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm` to the html.

Why does it do this and how can I get it to stop?

---

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SelectList>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <%=Html.BeginRouteForm(String.Empty, new {Action = "Search"}, FormMethod.Get) %>


    <%:Html.DropDownList("worklist", this.Model )%>

    <br />

    <input type="submit" />

    <% Html.EndForm(); %>
</asp:Content>
```

---

```
<h2>Index</h2>

<form action="/Site/Search" method="get">System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm


<select Label="Worklists" id="worklist" name="worklist"><!-- Options -->
</select>

<br />

<input type="submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're calling it incorrectly. `<%=` means, more or less, "treat the result as a string." The default implementation of `.ToString()` writes the class name. You could use `<%` and that would fix the problem. But better still is to use it with `using`, which is more idiomatic for MVC and relieves you of the need to call `EndForm` explicitly. In other words, change your code:

```
<%=Html.BeginRouteForm(String.Empty, new {Action = "Search"}, FormMethod.Get) %>
    ...
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

... to:

```
<% using (Html.BeginRouteForm(String.Empty, new {Action = "Search"}, FormMethod.Get)) { %>
    ...
<% } %>
```